# machinelearning4j seems to cause disk going offline

Tags: java, windows, gradle, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

fooling around with deeplearning4j in eclipse oxygen on windows 8.1

usually after running the [LR sample program](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/feedforward/regression/RegressionMathFunctions.java) a few times and perhaps doing a gradle build, my d: drive (containing the source code) goes off-line. comes back after a reboot.

has anyone else experience this?

thanks

edit. this happened again when i tried to do a build with gradle from eclipse.

Launching Gradle tasks failed due to an error connecting to the Gradle build.
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip'.

Failed to release lock on task history cache (D:\ray\dev\ml\trygradleanddl4j.gradle\2.14.1\taskArtifacts)
The device is not ready
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
...
org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockFileAccess.clearLockInfo(LockFileAccess.java:73)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock$2.stop(DefaultFileLockManager.java:228)
    ... 74 more

Answer (score 0):

I *highly* doubt this is the case. There are likely some side effects from running the examples that point to a larger problem with your setup. It's impossible for us to reproduce this on any of our setups let alone having seen any users run in to this. It has to be something specific with your setup.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "my setup"? i used gradle to download the jars and i have the source from the examples. thanks

Comment: Generally something OS specific. I haven't seen this among any of our users. If there's a problem at all that correlates with deeplearning4j, it's not going to be the deeplearning4j software itself. It's going to be a side effect of a larger problem like runing any compute intensive job causes problems.